# Does Three.js support ANGLE_instanced_arrays?

Tags: three.js, geometry

I've tried finding an answer to this question but I couldn't. I am still very bad at WebGL and I only use Three.js to do my work. Do Three.js Mesh Constructors support the use of ANGLE_instanced_arrays to do Geometry Instancing?

If there is browser support for the [ANGLE_instanced_array](http://blog.tojicode.com/2013/07/webgl-instancing-with.html) is there a way to create the THREE.Mesh() with *Geometry Instancing* rather than relying on *"Pseudo Instancing"* ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Yes it does (at least in r72). There are several examples that use the `ANGLE_instanced_arrays` extension like: http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_buffergeometry_instancing, http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_buffergeometry_instancing_billboards, http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_buffergeometry_instancing_dynamic, http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_buffergeometry_instancing_interleaved_dynamic

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't appear that way. I've been looking for an authoritative answer to this question and haven't been able to find confirmation, but given that a search for the constant "ANGLE_instanced_arrays" on github [yields no matches](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=ANGLE_instanced_arrays) my guess is that it is not implemented.

Comment: try to include important points from the link, sometimes the link may change

Answer (score 0):

THREE 's WebGLRenderer.supportsInstancedArrays() is now WebGLRenderer.extensions.get( 'ANGLE_instanced_arrays' ).
[DeprecatedList](https://threejs.org/docs/api/deprecated/DeprecatedList.html)

var geo = **new THREE.InstancedBufferGeometry()**;

```
// src/core/InstancedBufferGeometry.js
 isInstancedBufferGeometry: true,...

// src/renderers/WebGLRenderer.js
if ( geometry && geometry.isInstancedBufferGeometry ) {
     if ( geometry.maxInstancedCount > 0 ) { renderer.renderInstances( geometry, drawStart, drawCount );
......

//src/renderers/webgl/WebGLIndexedBufferRenderer.js
function renderInstances( geometry, start, count ) {
var extension = extensions.get( 'ANGLE_instanced_arrays' );
```